# Async. Перестает работать код после прогонки через webpack babel

Tags: javascript, webpack, асинхронность, babel

Опробовал этот код на codepan и все работает отлично. Но после того, как я перегоняю его через babel выпадает ошибка. Ниже прикреплю код и скрины ошибки (Может плагин для async отдельный нужен, в общем подскажите пожалуйста

```
async function getPostAsync(id) {
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`,
  );

  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
}

getPostAsync(1)
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

[image: Подсвечивание в самом коде]
[image: Ошибка в консоли]

Comment: Порядок скриптов на странице проверь. И не потерялся ли manifest.